# Get Treeview Parent/GrandParent from Child

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

[image]
I have 4 Levels in my tree view and want to find Parent/GrandParent of child selected at 4th level. Is there any way in WPF to find parent of selected item in Tree View.

Comment: I usually make my own TreeView Class which inherits the standard TreeView .  Then add property Parent.  When I build my TreeView I fill in the parent property so it is easy to move up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a link to the parent in the child and it might be best to only ever create a child element via the parent:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children = new List<Child>();
    public void AddChild(string childArg1)
    {
        Children.Add(new Child(this, childArg1);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public Parent Parent { get; private set; }
    public Child(Parent parent, string childArg1)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Then you can access:

```
Parent p = childInstance.Parent;
```

Comment: @Pankaj please confirm this as the answer if it has solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
public class TreeStructure
{
    public TreeStructure Parent { get; set; }
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public List<TreeStructure> Childrens { get; set; } = new List<TreeStructure>();

    public TreeStructure(decimal id, TreeStructure parent)
    {
        Id = id;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public TreeStructure GetTopParent()
    {
        var tree = this;
        while (tree.Parent != null)
        {
            tree = tree.Parent;
        }

        return tree;
    } 
}
```